# How to alternate between strings to make new array?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in a string, which is then divided into two strings, `a` and `b`. I want to perform some logic that will take the first word from `a`, append it to an array, then take the first word from `b` and append it to the same array. I'd like to loop through both strings until the array contains every other word from both strings. For example:

Start with

```
a = 'Hello are today'
b = 'how you'
```

End with

```
x = ['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today']
```

Comment: Can you shared what you've tried so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Why don't you just split each string into a list of words, say `alist` and `blist`, and then iterate over the pair of lists, alternately appending to the output list, as available. Simple stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner that does it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [word for t in itertools.zip_longest(a.split(), b.split()) for word in t if word]
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today']
```

Comment: Is there a way to do so without itertools?

Comment: @supernova, You can define a function called `zip_longest` yourself to avoid `itertools`: see example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop to iterate over the strings and add the words if they are within range:

```
def concate_strings(a, b):
    a = a.split()
    b = b.split()
    x = []
    for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
        if i < len(a):
            x.append(a[i])
        if i < len(b):
            x.append(b[i])
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 'Hello are today'
    b = 'how you'
    print(concate_strings(a, b))
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today']
```

**Alternate solution:**

You may have more than two strings and want to concatenate them together. In that case, you can pass a list of strings to the method and then concatenate them as their split length is within range.

```
def concate_strings_multiple(strings):
    x = []
    for i in range(max([len(s.split()) for s in strings])):
        for s in strings:
            if i < len(s.split()):
                x.append(s.split()[i])
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 'Hello are today'
    b = 'how you'
    print(concate_strings_multiple([a, b]))
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today']
```